# HTTP POST works in file browser but not when running in Apache

Tags: javascript, python, html, apache

I have a simple webpage that sends a HTTP POST request to (as of now) the localhost on the push of a button.  When i open the HTML file in a browser (chrome), it works just fine.  The button sends the POST request and the server shows that the data came in.

When i run the very same file in apache2, somehow the post request is either not send by the javascript or not recieved by the webserver.  I do npt think it is the latter as the server shows me any type of connection attempt, even in bad requests etc.

I have a feeling this has to do with the URL that i am using when i run apache.  It seems like the path should be changed when it is running on the localhost.  The apache port is running on the default port 80 and my server is running on port 5000

the html file that works when just opened:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<title>My jQuery JSON Web Page</title>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

JSONTest = function() {

    var resultDiv = $("#resultDivContainer");

    $.ajax({
        url: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/data",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify({"apiKey": "23462"}),
        success: function (result) {
            switch (result) {
                case true:
                    processResponse(result);
                    break;
                default:
                    resultDiv.html(result);
            }
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert(xhr.status);
        alert(thrownError);
        }
    });
};

</script>
</head>
<body>

<h1>My jQuery JSON Web Page</h1>

<div id="resultDivContainer"></div>

<button type="button" onclick="JSONTest()">JSON</button>

</body>
</html>
```

and the webserver (python flask app):

```
#Flask restful webserver
#Hunter
#2 April 2016

from random import randint
import time
import datetime
import json
import decimal
from flask import Flask, jsonify, abort, request, make_response, url_for

app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path="")

#standard error handlers
@app.errorhandler(400)
def bad_request(error):
    return make_response(jsonify({'error': 'Bad request'}), 400)

@app.errorhandler(404)
def not_found(error):
    return make_response(jsonify({'error': 'Not found'}), 404)

@app.route('/api/data', methods=['POST', 'OPTIONS'])
def post_data():
    if request.method == 'OPTIONS':
        headers = {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST, GET, OPTIONS',
            'Access-Control-Max-Age': 1000,
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'origin, x-csrftoken, content-type, accept',
        }
        return '', 200, headers
    data = json.loads(request.data)
    print data
    print 'here'

    return jsonify({'result': 'true'}), 201





if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Inspect the actual request and/or errors thrown in browser dev tools network and console for clues. Also haven't mentioned if alerts in error handler are firing or not

Comment: what does *"run the very same file in apache2"* mean? Do you serve the file via a local Apache installation instead of using Flasks static files serving feature?